# Grep for matching pattern but exclude particular string

Tags: grep, pattern-matching

I've file containing various log lines, and I want to `grep` for a pattern but exclude when `message:com.mycompany.excluded` , so basically following should be returned :

```
"The log found this message blah, message:com.blahblah"
"The log found this message blah2, message:com.blahblah2"
"The log found this message foobar, message:com.mycompany"
"The log found this message blah, message:com.mycompany.included"
```

but not :

```
 "The log found this message blah, message:com.mycompany.excluded"
```

I'm using this pattern, but it would not work for excluding `com.mycompany.excluded`

`grep "The log found this message.*message:.*" "mylogs.txt"`

Comment: You should include some lines that don't match `The log found this message.*message:.*` in your example to make it clearer that you do need to match that regexp too. And add the expected output given your sample input.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/The log found this message.*message:/ && !/com.mycompany.excluded/' "mylogs.txt"
```

There's various ways to make it more robust but they're probably not necessary (depending on what the rest of your log file looks like).

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is `sed`, not `grep`:

`sed -i .bak 's/^.*excluded//' mylogs.txt`

(The `-i .bak` creates a backup of your original file with the extension `.bak`; this would leave you with `mylogs.txt` and `mylogs.txt.bak`, with `mylogs.txt` having the undesired lines removed.)